# Prevent re-initialization of Provider in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I am currently experiencing an issue with my Flutter web app. When I open a page in a new tab, the providers reinitialize. This behavior is similar to how a page refresh works in a traditional web application. As a result, I have lost my saved state. Is there any way to save it without relying on local storage and access it across all my tabs? Please find below the code I am using to open the page in a new tab:

```
html.window.open('/#${Result.routeName}', "_blank");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative state management package, `bloc` offers a solution under `hydrated_bloc` package what you are looking for.

But on provider side maybe you can use `BroadcastChannel` class to solve that but creating a local storage would be much easier and effective.

You can create a local storage with

```
flutter_secure_storage: 

or 

shared_preferences:
```

Then you can simply create a method to write which states you want to recover after routing. After it on the new page just recover those states and delete that recovery-storage.

That will be the easiest solution I guess or you can move up to `bloc`.

Have a great coding session :)